# Shell script for authenticating github credential

Tags: git, shell, github

I have shell script and I am cloning master branch into some directory. However I have other steps to follow once I successfully cloned master branch in specified directory. Is there anyway with below command that it returns something true|false so I can do other steps?

```
git clone -b master  https://github.com/someuser/project.git /path/to/dir
```

I have other way around for this but wanted to know if there is some possibility of this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git clone` command uses exit code 0 on success and non-zero on failure,
just like any well-behaving program.
You can use this in conditional statements, for example:

```
if git clone -b master repourl /path/to/dir; then
    # clone successful -> run setup script
else
    echo fatal: could not clone repo
fi
```